# Objective-C equivalent of "head->size--;"

Tags: objective-c, pointers, linked-list

Writing a program that uses Kunth's dancing links algorithm. In C++ I'd use

```
n1->head->size--
```

this works,

```
[[n1 head]setSize:[[n1 head]size] - 1];
```

but it doesn't seem idiomatic. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
n1.head.size--;
```